# Linega of Sri Sampradaya (Shri Ram Mantraraj Parampara)

Tags: ramanandacharya, srisampradaya, guru-parampara, ramananda, ramanandasampradaya

**Lineage of Sri Sampradaya** Shri Ram Mantraraj Parampara by Anantanandacharya

Answer (score 1):

[image]
परधाम्नि स्थितोरामः पुण्डरीकायतेक्षणः ।
सेवया परयाजुष्टो जानक्यै तारकं ददौ ॥१॥

श्रियः श्रीरपिलोकानां दुःखोद्धरण हेतवे ।
हनूमते ददौ मन्त्रं सदारामङ्प्रिसेविने ॥२॥

In the divine abode of Saketa, Lord Rama with eyes like expansive lotus petals, pleased by the devotion, bestowed the transcendental "Shri Rama Taraka Mantra" upon Sita Ji, making her the recipient of this sacred mantra for the first time. Goddess of Maha-Lakshmi, Shri Janaki Ji, bestowed the "Shri Rama Mantra Raj" upon Shri Hanuman Ji, who tirelessly served the divine feet of Lord Rama, in order to uplift and relieve the downtrodden and sorrowful souls from the cycle of worldly suffering.

ततस्तु ब्रह्मणा प्राप्तं मुह्यमानेन मायया ।
कल्पान्तरे तु रामो वै ब्रह्मणे दत्तवानिमम् ॥३॥

मन्त्रराज जपं कृत्त्वा धाता निर्मातृतां गतः ।
त्रयीसारमिमं धातुर्वशिष्ठो लब्धवान् परम् ॥४॥

Enchanted by Lord Hanuman, Brahma Ji acquired the Shri Rama Mantra. In a different era, Lord Rama Himself bestowed the Shri Rama Mantra upon Brahma Ji, and by chanting this supreme mantra, the Creator attains the power to rebuild the world. The essence of all three Vedas, this Mantra Raj was received by Sage Vashishtha from Lord Brahma himself.

पराशरो वशिष्ठाच्य मुद्रासंस्कार संयुतम् ।
मन्त्रराज परं लब्ध्वा कृतकृत्योवभूव ह ॥५॥

पराशरस्य सत्पुत्रो व्यासः सत्यवती सुतः ।
पितुः षडक्षरं लब्ध्वा चक्रेवेदोपबृंहणम् ॥६॥

Endowed with the Pancha Samskaras including the impression of Bow and Arrow by Sage Vashishtha, the blessed Sage Parashara obtained this Mantra Raj and became supremely blessed. Satyavati's son, Sage Vedavyasa, received the Shadakshara Shri Rama Mantra from his father Sage Parashara, and thus he attained the fortune of understanding the essence of the Vedas, as well as gained the power to write Ved-Vedanta and History.

व्यासोऽपि बहुशिष्येषु मन्वानो शुभ योग्यताम् ।
परमहंस वर्य्याय शुकदेवाय दत्तवान् ॥६॥

शुकदेव कृपापात्रो ब्रह्मचर्य व्रतेस्थितः ।
नरोत्तमस्तु तच्छिष्यो निर्वाणपदवीं गतः ॥७॥

Sage Vyasa imparted this mantra to numerous deserving disciples, among whom the chief was the supreme among sages, Shri Shukadeva Ji. Due to the profound grace of Shri Shukadeva Ji, revered sage Purushottamacharya, also known as Shri Bodhayana Maharishi, who was deeply committed to lifelong celibacy, attained the state of enlightenment through this Sri Ram Mantra.

सचापि परमाचार्यो गङ्गाधराय सूरये ।
मन्त्राणां परमं तत्त्वं राममन्त्रं प्रदत्तवान् ॥८॥

गङ्गाधरात्सदाचार्यस्ततो रामेश्वरो यतिः ।
द्वारानन्दस्ततो लब्ध्वा पर ब्रह्मरतोऽभवत् ॥९॥

The illustrious Acharya Sri Purushottamacharya also known as Maharishi Bodhayana lovingly transmitted the profound essence of mantras, the Mahamantra Shri Rama Taraka Mantra, to Shri Gangadharacharya. Shri Gangadharacharya Ji passed it on to Shri Sadanandacharya Ji, and Shri Sadanandacharya Ji passed it to Yati Sri Rameshwaranandacharya Ji. Shri Rameshwaranandacharya Ji, than passed this Shadakshar Sri Ram Mantra to Shri Dwaranandacharya Ji Maharaj.

देवानन्दस्तु तच्छिष्यः श्यामानन्दस्ततोऽग्रहीत ।
तत्सेवया श्रुतानन्दचिदानन्दस्ततोऽभवत् ॥१०॥

पूर्णानन्दस्ततो लब्ध्वा श्रियानन्दाय दत्तवान् ।
हर्यानन्दो महायोगी श्रियानन्दाङ्घ्रि सेवकः ॥११॥

Devoted disciple of Dwaranandacharya Ji, Devanandacharya Ji, was initiated with the Shri Rama Mantra. Then, Shyamanandacharya Ji, a disciple of Devanandacharya Ji, was initiated with the Shri Rama Mantra. Shyamanandacharya Ji then bestowed the Shri Rama Mantra Raj upon his devoted servant Shrutanandacharya Ji. Shrutanandacharya Ji then initiated Chidanandacharya Ji into the Shri Rama Mantra, who subsequently initiated Purnanandacharya Ji with the Taraka Mantra. Purnanandacharya Ji then passed on the mantra to Shriyanandacharya Ji. At the feet of Shriyanandacharya Ji, the qualified disciple and great yogi Shri Haryanandacharya Ji received initiation with the Shri Rama Taraka Mantra.

हर्यांनन्दस्य शिष्योहि राघवानन्द इत्यसौ ।
यस्य वै शिष्यतां प्राप्तो रामानन्दः स्वयं हरि ॥१२॥

The disciple of Haryanandacharya Ji, Shri Raghavanandacharya Ji Maharaj, accepted the discipleship of Ramanandacharya who was Himself Lord Sri Ram.

Lineage of Sri Sampraday:-

1)Sri Rama—

2)Srimati Sita—

3)Sri Hanuman—

4)Sri Brahma—

5)Sri Vasishta—

6)Sri Parashara—

7)Sri Veda Vyasa—

8)Sri Sukadevacharya—

9)Sri Bodhayan— (Bodhāyan Vrittikar)

10)Sri Gangadharacharya—

11)Sri Sadaanandacharya—

12)Sri Rameshwaranandacharya—

13)Sri Dvaranandacharya—

14)Sri Devanandacharya—

15)Sri Shyamanandacharya—

16)Sri Shrutanandacharya—

17)Sri Chidanandacharya—

18)Sri Purnanandacharya—

19)Sri Shriyanandacharya—

20)Sri Haryanandacharya—

21)Sri Raghavananadacharya—

22)Sri Ramanandacharya (Anand Bhashyakar)

—This is the complete lineage of Sri Sampradaya which starts from Sri SitaRam. Do not interlink Shri Ramanand Sampraday with Shri Ramanuj Sampraday Both Sampradayas are highly respectable but have different lineage since beginning. Shri Ramanujacharya is not a part of Shri Rāmānanda Samprday neither Shri Ramanandacharya is a part of Shri Ramanuja Samprday. Above Shri Agradas Swami lineage was kept as a proof in 1921 Ujjain Kumbh debate which flushed all the doubts that both Sampradayas are interlinked.